# Cross-site list of the logged-in users posts on all sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, linked-accounts

I recently answered a question and found out the next day that it had vanished.  I suspect it was migrated, but I don't want to go randomly opening 10 accounts in the hope that I might find my answer.

**Feature Request:** A cross-site list (maybe a page on stackexchange.com?) that shows all of the logged-in user's posts on all sites, regardless of whether they have an account on that site or not.

Is there a better way to do this that I missed?

Comment: [This one?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/35138/been-thinking-about-trying-to-learn-to-program-on-android/35144#35144)

Comment: @balpha: No, not that one.  It was on SU and I suspected it was migrated to Apple.SE.  I answered the day before yesterday I think.

Comment: Ah okay, you had found it already. I thought you were still searching :)

Comment: @balpha: I *am* still looking, just not for that answer.  :-)

Comment: +1 to this, I sent a friend to SU to post a question she had that I didn't know the answer to, only to have the question disappear before I could set a watch on it. Turns out it got moved to another site, but it took us hours to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Status completed.](https://stackexchange.com/users/dc14e6e9-8719-4448-bd0c-c2331ede3c0a?tab=activity)